# Is it possible to use tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph with Keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, quantization, tensorflow-lite

Is it possible to use `tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph` for model quantiation with already trained Keras model?

As I understand I can import `tf.Graph` from Keras model, but can I finetune it after modification with `tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph` ?

I was able to call `tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph(input_graph=K.get_session().graph, quant_delay=int(0))` after model definition and model load, but get:

```
2019-02-22 14:56:24.216742: W tensorflow/c/c_api.cc:686] Operation '{name:'global_average_pooling2d_1_1/Mean' id:3777 op device:{} def:{global_average_pooling2d_1_1/Mean = Mean[T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, keep_dims=false](conv2d_15_1/act_quant/FakeQuantWithMinMaxVars:0, global_average_pooling2d_1_1/Mean/reduction_indices)}}' was changed by updating input tensor after it was run by a session. This mutation will have no effect, and will trigger an error in the future. Either don't modify nodes after running them or create a new session.
```

At least I was able to save model with uint8 weights when converting to keras->tensorflow->tflite, as I understand input to model and inference is still fp32.

```
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
        graph_def_file='tf_model.pb',
        input_arrays=input_node_names,
        output_arrays=output_node_names)

converter.post_training_quantize = True

tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11105

Comment: In https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27880 you may find how to solve the problem